# SpringBoot JPA Err: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 728890494

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 728890494, when hibernate ddl for initial db.
if I change

```java
EntityStatusConvert2 implements AttributeConverter<EntityStatus2, Byte>
```

to

```java
EntityStatusConvert2 implements AttributeConverter<EntityStatus2, Integer>
```

it works very well.
And I try to write myself Dialect

```java
this.registerHibernateType(728890494,org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER.name)
```

This problem still exists。

The entity and converter code :

```java
@Entity
public class Channel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;
    /**.... */
    @Convert(converter = EntityStatusConvert2.class)
    EntityStatus2 st;

}

public class EntityStatusConvert2 implements AttributeConverter<EntityStatus2, Byte> {
    @Override
    public Byte convertToDatabaseColumn(EntityStatus2 entityStatus) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public EntityStatus2 convertToEntityAttribute(Byte aByte) {
        return EntityStatus2.OK;
    }
}

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 728890494
```

The code above is running in SpringBoot 2.1.4,hibernate 5.3.9final.

Comment: What dB dialect you confirmed in hibernate?

Comment: I use springboot,it auto config it.application.proterties only url=jdbc:mysql://...